# Where to store the decryption key in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I am working on react app which fetches the API on the user responses. 
API response are encrypted and I get decryption key before making any API (via secure method).

I need to store the decryption key so that I can decrypt the API response every single time.
Currently I store the decryption key in component state. 
which can be seen very easily by anyone using react-dev tool

I don't need to store the decryption locally, it changes very time user login.

Comment: You cannot hide secrets from the user. That said, I suggest looking at `Window.crypto` and seeing if there's anything useful in there. Also see if there's a way to use the computer's TPM (if present) to perform cryptographic tasks without needing to reveal secret keys - this can be done in a client web-app if you're able to run a separate native application that exposes the required functionality using a built-in micro web-server (this is how Dell's website's Service Tag helper works).

Comment: @Dai I just wanted that, they only get the UI element, not full API response object

Comment: The only correct answer here is to build a proxy service that will store the key and decrypt the messeges as they flow through. A webclient can’t hold any secrets.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf You response seems good to me. can you help me how can I do this

Comment: No i can’t help you, but as i said, you need to build som form of backend service that fetches and holds the key, and your frontend needs to call that service and all request needs to be proxied between. But the entire thing is bad design. All i wanted to say here was that you never store anything sensitive in the browser. Never

Answer (score -1):

The key needs to be stored inside an httpOnly cookie, a special kind of cookie that’s only sent in HTTP requests to the server, and it’s never accessible (both for reading or writing) from JavaScript running in the browser.

By the way, this is the way JWT token verification works as well. So you can use the same mechanism.

PS: Ignore my previous comment, I was just trying to give you an alternative without giving my thought to it

Comment: This is a bad answer. If you encrypt it and place it in local storage. What do you do with the key that used to encrypt the local storage with? Nothing is secret in the browser.

Comment: `If custom secret-key is provided as mentioned below in APIs, then the library will pick that otherwise it will generate yet another very secure unique password key using PBKDF2, which will be further used`

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use Cookies for storing your decryption key, but now that's your choice that you need to persist the cookie or make it available for the session.

You can encyrpt cookies making use of [cookie-encryption](https://github.com/hex7c0/cookie-encryption)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I want to **hide** the decryption key from the user. user can see decryption key from cookie

Comment: @PURUSHOTTAMSHUKLA: But they will not be able to know your hash function and salt value. Encrypted cookie value will not be decrypted if they're not provided. These will be the part of your config files that you can keep on server or either if you will keep them as a part of code then also these files will be minified using webpack compiled code. So I think it will not be an issue.

Comment: Not see your hash function or salt? What are talking about? If i have the key i can easy guess the hash function and brute force the salt. And seriously, you think minification is some sort of security feature? What?

Comment: I also suggested you to keep your key in some config files that will reside on your server and from the frontend you will request that key.